# How do I make incremental value changes in microns?

Tags: interface

I recently got into 3D printing and I am using Blender until that no longer becomes feasible to do so. I am working in real world measurements in Blender, using meters. I have a need to move my background images in the x and y within millionths of a meter increments. Holding down Shift and dragging seems to move the image in centimeters and I can't figure out a way to get a finer adjustment than than except typing in values by hand which is cumbersome. Does anyone know if it is possible to make adjustments within millionths of a meter (microns)?

Comment: Your question makes a really good point: that moving background images in fine increments should allow more precise control than it currently does. Consider also the option of simply working at 10 times the actual scale, then scaling down 0.1 and applying scale at the last step. Not sure if it would make sense for your workflow, but it's one more way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You may use an ***Empty (Image)*** for your background image (*Add*-->*Empty*-->*Image*). In the *Empty* panel of the *Data* header you have the same settings as for the *Background Images* panel of the *properties shelf.
[image]*

In the *Scene* header set the units to ***Metric***.
[image]

Now you can input a precise value to translate the image.
[image]

Comment: I can enter precise values the way that I am doing it now. I am looking for a way to scroll, drag, press an arrow or something to move incrementally up or down in any value field 1 micron at a time, without having to keep manually entering new values to try and line things up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure about what you wish but setting metric units scale to 0.0001 makes translation widget move objects by 1um

Note: if you change the scale to .0001, you may need to scale up your existing model model by 10000 times, and to be able visualize it in 3d viewport, also adjust clipping, setting maximum to (say, at least) 10m (10 meters)

this is what I mean:

[image]

does this help you?

Comment: You can change the scale of the viewport as well. Press **N** and look for **Scale** in the display section.

Comment: @cegaton I didn't remember, thanks! I wrote "you may need" because I don't know much about its model and its expected scale. Being related to 3d printing, I expect the object scale to be somewhat bigger than a few millimiters... but it may be...